# How to get UINavigationController child view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, subview, reloaddata

I have one detail view controller in splitView - SearchDeatilViewController. But that view controller is attached to navigation controller.
How can I get that subview to take controll of him?

I tried like this, to reload sub view tableView:

```
SearchDetailViewController *detail1 = (SearchDetailViewController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[detail1.tableView reloadData];
```

But it gives me error:

> -[UINavigationController reloadTable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

It seems that the object I get in variable detail1 is of type navigationController. Obviously I need to go one level deeper. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Why does the error say `reloadTable`, while your code says `reloadData`?

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. What do you mean by "How can I get that subview to take controll of him"?

Comment: Ok. I have splitView which has two views: masterView and detailView. DetailView has also navigationController. But I want to get detailView to reloadTable in it. But when I get view controllers from splitView at position 1 I get top most controller and that is navigationController.
How can I get view that is under navigationController that I get from splitView ???

Comment: Douwe Maan: It actually says: 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UINavigationController tableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4ca6a50'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Just tagged subviews and than access them with [myView viewWithTag:X] and it works.